# Verify users email

Tags: email, authentication, verification

When a user sets up an account for an application and uses their email address for a username, how do I verify that the email address they entered is a valid email?  Specifically, without sending a verification email.

Comment: The only way to be sure that an email address leads to an inbox is to send an email to it. Validating formats and querying DNS and/or mail servers aren't guaranteed to return a sound result.

Comment: Without verification I don't think there is way to do this

Comment: Well, if all the big players send verification e-mails... think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Valid e-mail address eq php filter_var('root@stackoverflow.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
2. when user finish retyping e-mail onfocus send ajax request
3. DNS query for e-mail svr eq search in google for source script "valid email by dns github"